# Optimal Way To Generate A Balanced Binary Search Tree From A Stream Of Sorted Numbers

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, data-stream

I have an input stream of integers coming in an ascending order, my task is to create a balance binary search tree out of that stream, on the fly. I have gone through the link:[BBST from a stream of integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236172/create-a-balanced-binary-search-tree-from-a-stream-of-integers) and understood that we can make use of Red-Black trees. The thing is, I am looking for more optimal solutions that use 'sorted information' from the input data.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your responses @Ami and Emmett. Actually, I am looking for a building a Red-Black tree using that 'sorted' data stream in the initialization phase. This stream contains keys. So later, I need to do random Insert/update/delete operations on it. So, any specific solution that uses sorted information and runs better during the initialization phase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a red-black tree but always start your insertion at the last node inserted, rather than the root, and use a bottom up insertion algorithm, insertion is O(1) amortized. This means constructing the tree will cost O(n), not Ω(n log n).

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me with any resources or exact logic for bottom up insertion? Thanks for your solution, looks like I have to do this way.

Comment: Ha ha - I recognize you from the amortized insertion cost. Very nice use of it here!

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are coming in sorted order, then probably the simplest and most efficient thing to do is just to push each one to the end of a [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array) (an array that doubles its size whenever it becomes full, for example).

1. Pushing into the array is [amortized *O(1)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Performance).
2. Searches in a sorted array are *O(log(n))* using [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). Moreover, it's logarithmic time with very low constants.

Despite its simplicity, a sorted array is a type of a blanced binary search tree.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the amount of data is unknown. Therefore, this tree *must* be self balancing, regardless of whether the input has a pattern or not (ascending order).

If O(log n) insertion times are not acceptable in this case (say for red-black trees) then I'm at a loss as to why you need to store this in balanced binary tree form in the first place. A binary search on a dynamic array is just as fast as a tree, with amortized O(1) insertion time.

If the size of the stream is known before hand, then of course building the tree would be much easier.